# Driving a linear actuator from a home automation system

Tags: power-supply, relay

I am not exactly an expert into electrical engineering. I have a Linak LA12 IC linear actuator, and am trying to drive the motor from two outputs on my home automation system. The home automation system has a 24V DC (max 500mA) output module. The motor will reverse direction as the current is reversed.

The actuator will drive a mechanism that will raise and lower a projector hidden in a compartment in the ceiling.

Here is my planned circuit.

[image]

The power source on the left is a 24V 5A laptop power brick, and the power source and switches in the middle emulates the 24V 500mA outputs on my home automation system.

I have been told that there is a potentially a problem with this circuit if the power brick is grounded internally. I do not understand what this issue is or how to solve it.

My question is: do you see any issues with this circuit?

Comment: I would add limit switches in the control side to remove power from the motor when it reaches end-of-travel in either direction.

Comment: @PeterBennett: I failed to mention that the motor cuts out itself. My plan was to program the automation system to run slightly longer than necessary to raise lower it using a timer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this circuit will work as you intended. It took me a minute to decipher your use of S1 and S2 to represent the two power signals from the home automation system. It's not totally clear, but I think I understand what you meant. I'm also assuming that the relays you've chosen are appropriately sized since you didn't specify any part numbers.

I'd add a few circuit protection elements for safety and to prolong the life of the system.

Mainly, a fuse in series with the power brick. This is a fairly high-wattage motor. If it stalls on something or shorts internally, you'll have a lot of energy pumping into the system until you notice the fault - which may not happen until you start smelling the smoke.

A large, fast switching diode across each relay may be a good idea as well. When the contactor suddenly separates - but before it makes contact with the + side of the power supply - the inductance of the motor will spike the voltage looking for a path for the current. It may cause an arc to form from the contactor to one of the other terminals of the relay. The arcing could damage the relay over time. A diode would give a path for the current to flow back into the power supply for that split second before the contactor is finished moving. The anode of the diode would be connected to the motor side of each relay and the cathode to the pin connected to the positive side of the power supply.

Comment: This all sounds like sensible (and I can understand what you are saying, which is a big deal for me ;) ) improvements that I will definitely implement. As mentioned I don't know much about electronics, so I haven't gotten to the part of picking actual components yet. I assume 24V, 6A relays will being enough (the motor specs say maximum 4.2A under load). Please correct me if I am wrong. And thank you very much for the answer!

Comment: Relays are cheap, so I'd go with a higher current part to give yourself a factor of safety. I see everything from 10A to 40A relays on digikey for less than three bucks.

Comment: Ok, based on that statement, I assume that I can safely overdimension the relays. Bonus question - would you create a PCB for a simple curcuit like this, or would you buy DIN mountable relays and fuses instead?

Comment: DIN would be fine or even a perf board. The cost of manufacturing a PCB for so few parts may not be worth it.